# Nested QMap - How to insert without instantiating

Tags: qt, qmap

```
QMap<QString,int> map;

QMap<int,QMap<QString,int>> table;

QMap<QString,int>::iterator iter = map.begin();
int i = 0;
while (iter != map.end()) 
{
   if (condition) {
      table.insert(i++,iter.key(),iter.value());  // <--- this is obviously wrong
   else
      ++iter;
}
```

So bascially I need to filter our data in map and insert them as new QMap as a value in the table QMap.
How to go around with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Qt 5.1, when compiling as c++11, you could [use an initializer list](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmap.html#QMap-1):

```
table.insert( i++, QMap<QString,int> {{iter.key(),iter.value()}} );
```

But the question title says "without instantiating", and that is not possible. This is just another constructor.

Comment: the above returns an error "no matching constructor" .(Qt 5.14.0)

Comment: If you use Qmake (project.pro) you need: `CONFIG += c++11`, if you use CMake, then `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)`